# Java: File i/o tuning

Tags: java, optimization, file-io

I attempted to create a sort-of file generator which spits out hardcoded messages to a file with slight alterations to some of the strings based on user input. Since I'm utilizaing polymorphism, I have multiple files and interfaces.

I'm finding myself passing a file parameters more times than one and is starting to rethink the way I've structured my program. Which brings me to ask, is there a huge performance impact from passing a file as a parameter to multiple methods?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you passing: a `File` object, an `OutputStream`, a `Writer`, or ...? Do you actually have a performance issue (and can you prove that it is caused by these method calls)? If not, I would rather focus on cleaning up the design.

Comment: Probably no perforamce impact, but it does sound like your application is badly structured.

Comment: I'm passing a BufferedWriter. But yes, I'm starting to think I need to refactor my whole program, haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no measurable performance impact from the number of parameters that you pass to a method.

However, repeatedly opening and closing a `java.io.File{Input|Output}Stream` does have a cost. And you need boilerplate try/finally code to ensure that the file is properly closed after use.

A better solution is to pass an `OutputStream` to your methods, and open the file once at the top-level method. This will also allow your code to be most easily tested: you can pass a `ByteArrayOutputStream` rather than a `FileOutputStream`.

Oh, and wrap your `FileOutputStream` in a `BufferedOutputStream`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're really passing around, and some code examples would be useful.

My first thought is that if you have performance issues, then you should be profiling your application. Writing a file will likely be the bottleneck, rather than argument passing (remember - you'll be passing *object references*, not the objects themselves).

But measure your application performance first, before you embark on any (possibly costly) refactorings.